# How do .NET AppDomains keep the hosted process alive?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, appdomain, unhandled

Say I have two AppDomains within a .NET/CLR process.

One of the AppDomains crashes due to a unhandled exception.

Would the other AppDomain still be running fine? What if the default AppDomain crashed otherwise?

I am just wondering on what keeps a process alive. Since AppDomains are completely seperate entities I assume the default AppDomain could crash and other AppDomains could continue?

Not even my C# book explicitly mentions what happens...

Comment: That's actually one of the primary purposes of AppDomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that if any of the domains you have created from your main thread crash, you will be fine. However, if your "entry domain" crashes, the others die as well.

Comment: Quick and to the point, thanks! Considering the default app domain creates other app domains at runtime this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, AppDomains are completed separete. Each domain has its own resources so when it crash, others are untached. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb506139(v=vs.110).aspx). If your default domain crashes all domains created from it will also failed I supposed.